# How to Convert a generic type list of data to another generic type list of data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I am trying to write a **Generic Base Service Class** where after receiving the fist generic list of data as the actual type of **Db Model Entity** need a conversion to a new **Generic View Model** type of data.

I have tried `list.ConvertAll()` but always getting a build error for `ConvertAll()` method.

I also tried `list.Cast<TVm>().ToList()` this solve the build error but getting the run time error.

Here are my code snips of all classes and interfaces. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

**Entity Class**

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [Index("IX_Id", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

**BaseViewModel Class**

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> where T: Entity
{        

    protected BaseViewModel() { }

    protected BaseViewModel(T model)
    {
        Id = model.Id;
        Created = model.Created;
        CreatedBy = model.CreatedBy;
        Modified = model.Modified;
        ModifiedBy = model.ModifiedBy;
        Active = model.Active;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

**IBaseService interface**

```
public interface IBaseService<T, TVm> where T : Entity where TVm : BaseViewModel<T>
{
    List<TVm> GetAll();
}
```

**BaseService Class**

```
public abstract class BaseService<TEntity, TVm> : IBaseService<TEntity, TVm> where TEntity: Entity where TVm : BaseViewModel<TEntity>
{
    protected  IBaseRepository<TEntity> Repository;

    protected BaseService(IBaseRepository<TEntity> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    public virtual  List<TVm> GetAll()
    {
        List<TVm> entities;
        try
        {
            List<TEntity> list = Repository.GetAll().ToList();
            entities =  list.Cast<TVm>().ToList(); //runtime error
            entities = list.ConvertAll(x => new TVm(x)); //build error
            entities = list.ConvertAll(new Converter<TEntity, TVm>(TEntity)); //build error
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {                
            throw new Exception(exception.Message);
        }

        return entities;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the build error it give you? and what is the runtime error? please edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an instance of a generic type, you need the `new()`-constraint on it. However, that does not allow you to pass any parameters to it. You could try either

1. Using Activator to create an instance, like this

   `entities = list.ConvertAll(x => (TVm)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TVm), x));`

or

2. Add the `new()`-constraint to `TVm` in the `BaseService` class signature, and add a method on the classes you pass to it as `TVm` that basically does what the current constructor does, but in a method, and call that after creating the new object.

Comment: Also you can use mapping tools like AutoMapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: 1 is very useful and working fine. I was tried 2 before asking the question but it was breaking my current implementation. That's why I refuse the adding new() constraint. Thanks a lot for your kind ans.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option you tried is `entities = list.ConvertAll(x => new TVm(x));`. The reason it fails compilation is that, in C# *inherited* classes doesn't necessarily need to have same constructor as *base class*. Instead you should initialize TVm inside `BaseService`. Additionally, your `try catch` block does nothing more than losing some data and affecting `StackTrace`, so you better remove it. Below code should work for you.

```
public abstract class BaseService<TEntity, TVm> 
    : IBaseService<TEntity, TVm> 
        where TEntity: Entity 
        where TVm : BaseViewModel<TEntity>, new()
{
    protected  IBaseRepository<TEntity> Repository;

    protected BaseService(IBaseRepository<TEntity> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    private TVm ConvertToViewModel(TEntity model)
    {
        return new TVm
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Created = model.Created,
            CreatedBy = model.CreatedBy,
            Modified = model.Modified,
            ModifiedBy = model.ModifiedBy,
            Active = model.Active,
        };
    }

    public virtual  List<TVm> GetAll()
    {
        List<TEntity> list = Repository.GetAll().ToList();
        List<TVm> entities = list.ConvertAll(x => ConvertToViewModel(x));
        return entities;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion. Therefor I am not using new () constraint it is not possible to create an instance of TVm.

Comment: @Md.SabbirAhamed, as I am not familiar with whole picture, it is possible that adding `new()` constraint is not accepteble for you. Anyway, I glad that your issue is resolved

Comment: Yes, I am happy that problem is solved :). Thank you again. Obviously your shared knowledge may be effective in  future in this or any others of my project